# get patch size in R terra

Tags: r, terra

I would like to get the patch sizes in a R terra object, and then filter patches above a threshold.

How do I get patch sizes in terra (and then filter)? The only output I see is patch ID (see plot).

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
x=app(r,function(x) ifelse(x< 400,NA,x))
y=patches(x)
plot(y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to avoid using `x[]` with `SpatRaster`s as that forces all data into memory. That works fine on these examples, but may fail with your real data. In this case, you can use `zonal` in stead.

You example data:

```
library(terra)
f = system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r = rast(f)
x = classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 400, NA))
y = patches(x)
```

To count the number of cells by patch

```
f = freq(y)
head(f)
#     layer value count
#[1,]     1     1   866
#[2,]     1     2     3
#[3,]     1     3     1
#[4,]     1     4     7
#[5,]     1     5     1
#[6,]     1     6     1
```

If you want the area covered by these cells, first use `cellSize`

```
z = cellSize(y,unit="km") |> zonal(y, sum)
head(z) |> round(2)
#  patches   area
#1       1 479.33
#2       2   1.66
#3       3   0.55
#4       4   3.88
#5       5   0.55
#6       6   0.55
```

Answer (score 2):

Sum the raster cell size grouped over the patch values:

```
> tapply(cellSize(y)[], y[], sum)
          1          13          17          20          23          29 
639851217.3   1660483.8    553747.8   3878797.0    554127.4    554601.7 
         31          43          46          48          49          50 
   554791.3   1666837.2   2779072.0   1112329.1    556306.5   2225698.9 
         51          52          53          54          55          56 
  1113180.5    556779.4    556873.9   1114031.3    557157.4    557251.9 
         57          58          61          62          63          64 
   557251.9   8921886.8   5592615.7    559798.4   1679866.0    559892.6 
         65 
   559892.6
```

For some reason my cell patches are numbered differently to yours, possibly I have an older version of terra (1.4.22). But I get 25 patches in total.

Comment: Thanks! How do I select patches over a threshold limit and then plot them?

Comment: That's a new question!

Comment: ...I think it was the "...(and then filter)" part of my question, but I can submit a new question.

Comment: I think its better as two questions - its possible either one could already have been answered and its good to keep the site with each post as a single Q+A for optimisation purposes.